# socket.io specific iOS device not receiving "group" emit

Tags: python, ios, socket.io, flask-socketio

I've built a small game in iOS using Socket IO (Flask GCP Back end in Python) and when two people are playing each other, I send updates like this

```
emit("update", {"state": OutgoingMatchState.player_moved.value,
                "move": move,
                "match_id": match.id,
                "id": player_id}, to=[home_player.sid, away_player.sid])
```

This has been working fine until recently I've been testing on my iPad... and this device specifically doesn't receive this type of `emit`

All other devices and simulators I've tested with work 100% of the time. Even when this device doesn't receive the update, the other device in the match does.

I'm also 100% sure the sids exist and are accurate... if I emit the same update without the `to=[]` part, it works for the iPad in question...

i.e. this works fine if the iPad makes the original socket post.

```
emit("update", {"state": OutgoingMatchState.player_moved.value,
                "move": move,
                "match_id": match.id,
                "id": player_id})
```

I need to send updates to both players in the game, I understand I could refactor to make a `room` for each match, but I'm wondering why this specific device isn't working.. Making a room based on `match.id` is a little messy considering I'd have to tidy them away after.

I've tried deleting the app on device and creating a new account, its also broken... it is the device specifically that doesn't like the `to=[]` updates.

To make sure I've tried `namespace="\"` and `include_self=True` but these also do not resolve the issue.

My manager looks like this... but like I said its working for all other devices

```
    private lazy var socketManager: SocketManager = {
        let config: SocketIOClientConfiguration = [.log(false), .compress]
        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: domain)!, config: config)
        manager.forceNew = true
        manager.reconnectWait = 3
        return manager
    }()
```

Turning on `.log(true)` nothing is received at this level either..

OK here is what is happening on the server side...

```
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
e9Hz8a1GQ-lxB3gvAAAO: Received packet MESSAGE data 1/,
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
e9Hz8a1GQ-lxB3gvAAAO: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/,
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
******* connection established *******
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
e9Hz8a1GQ-lxB3gvAAAO: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"JjExeVH003_sW2MqAAAQ"}
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
e9Hz8a1GQ-lxB3gvAAAO: Received packet MESSAGE data 1/,
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
e9Hz8a1GQ-lxB3gvAAAO: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/,
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
******* connection established *******
2022-09-20 16:25:33.000 ICT
e9Hz8a1GQ-lxB3gvAAAO: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"KlAr45jZhO1Nb9ApAAAR"}
```

In the server side code

```
@socketio.event()
def connect():
    print("******* connection established *******")
```

The connection is being established twice for this particular device, but the device is not hearing back about the second one....

Client side code:

```
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { [weak self] data, ack in
            print("*** Connected ***")
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            guard let d = data[safe: 1] as? [String: Any],
                    let sid = d["sid"] as? String else {
                print("Malformed connection data:", data)
                return
            }
            print(sid)
            print("*** SID ***")
            self.socketId = sid
            self.socketConnectionStatus.value = true
            self.matchDelegate?.connectionMade()
        }

        socket.on(clientEvent: .reconnect) { [weak self] data, ack in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
  
            print("**** Websocket reconnected ****")
            
            guard let d = data[safe: 1] as? [String: Any],
                  let sid = d["sid"] as? String else {
                print("Malformed connection data:", data)
                return
            }
            print(sid)
            print("*** SID ***")
            self.socketId = sid
            self.matchDelegate?.connectionMade()
            self.socketConnectionStatus.value = true
        }
```

The client only heard about `JjExeVH003_sW2MqAAAQ` and keeps that as its sid however some double connection is being made but its not reported on the client side.

printed:

```
*** Connected ***
JjExeVH003_sW2MqAAAQ
*** SID ***
```

Comment: The first thing you need to find out is if the server isn't sending the event, or if the client isn't accepting it. Without knowing that there isn't really a direction to take. Both the Socket.IO server and client can be configured to log all the internal details of the protocol, so you should be able to determine this relatively easily.

Comment: Turning on .log(true) there's no indication it's not accepting it. Let me trying turning on Logging on the CGP and make sure the server is sending to both clients then.

Comment: Ok looks like it's not sending the event and also this device keeps connecting twice in quick succession for some reason which is overwriting the sid

Comment: The client is sending disconnect packages. The `1/` message that the server receives from the client is a disconnect package. Not sure why, but it is sending both a disconnect and a connect in sequence. Something's wrong with your client.

Comment: I was having trouble in the past re-establishing connection, I've fixed this issue by being more gentle with my reconnection policy... however it'd be nice to hear about all changes, ideally I'd just get both sids in sequence, not sure why i don't hear about the second one.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR in the comments... I was being too tough with the disconnect / reconnect apis when trying to re-establish connection... being gentler with it worked. However, the second sid doesn't come through which is a concern.